# In Ruby, how can I get ARGV to read my input as a variable instead of a string?

Tags: ruby, argv

I have an assortment of test cases that I want to run.  The dumbed-down code is like this:

```
class TestCase
    def initialize(caseName)
        name = caseName
        ...a bunch more code...
    end
end    

@TC001 = new TestCase("Case 1")
@TC002 = new TestCase("Case 2")
...
@TC100 = new TestCase("Case 100")
```

Then I'm trying to pass in to the command line which test cases I need to run this time.  The Runner file looks something like:

```
testCaseArray = Array.new
i = 0
while i < ARGV.length
    testCaseArray < ARGV[i]
    i += 1
end

runTestCases(myArray)
    myArray.each do |thisCase|
        puts thisCase.name
     end
end

runTestCases(testCaseArray)
```

So then when I go to the command line and enter:

```
ruby Runner.rb @TC027 @TC030 @TC075
```

I get an error because it's not recognizing @TC027 as a variable but is instead recognizing it as a string, and (string).name isn't valid.

How do I get it to read the string as a variable?

Comment: Incidentally, that while-loop is equivalent to `testCaseArray = ARGV.dup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up an instance variable named by a string with `instance_variable_get`.

Comment: I tried changing "testCaseArray << ARGV[i]" to "testCaseArray << instance_variable_get(ARGV[i])" but now it's reading it as a nil.

Comment: @Leelluu: That would imply that the instance variable is not defined in the context where that code appears. If you stick `puts @TC002` or whatever in the same place, does that output anything?

Comment: @Leelluu: Then those instance variables aren't defined on whatever object is running that code.

Comment: Aha!  I moved where I was using instance_variable_get to the initial call, and that worked.  Thanks for all your help!